# Typescript generic to transform object property in key value object

Tags: typescript, sorting, mongoose

Sorting give me an object with columnName, and sorting direction, I would like to transform it into key value object for mongoose sorting.

The return values doesn't match I can't figure out what I'm missing

I have the following interfaces:

```
export enum SortDirection {
  asc = 'asc',
  desc = 'desc',
}

export class Sort<T> {
  columnName: keyof T
  direction: SortDirection
}

interface CriteriaRequestDto<T> {
  sort: Sort<T>
}

type SortQuery<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]?: SortDirection
}

buildSortQuery<T>(
    criteria: CriteriaRequestDto<T>,
  ): SortQuery<T> {
    if (!criteria || !criteria.sort) {
      return {}
    }
    const { columnName, direction } = criteria.sort

    return { [columnName]: direction }
  }
```

[Here my attemps on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzMg3gKGcuAcwgC5kQBXAWwCNoBuPZGqCCAEzIGcwpRDGAXxw4IlKsgDKAeyhgAIsFYIwwaSGxM4XBMgC8yAOTaEhgDRN2EHfqNWd5nMJyhIsRChlyAPABUAfJr4CNIANtQgAHJwVKTIANYQAJ7SMMi%20lkoQKmogZF4KWTnqTiKu0PBIaHxuwHAAShAAjhTWCmDSfoG4%20FyyYPn9XaU4YEkADp79AIqtUEldtj3IANqJScigCcmp6QC6APyDcorKqiXOMBQgxRo0FMCh7AWz0AsBABRMCDXQdWSoX58BrNVo8eQdLoWACUxzAr3mi2WwDSHwAhD9gLU4MgAD645AYoF1AB0fTk0KC%20GQrDAFCgGiwwnwzOQIRAPGwbLCEWisTMyHYRXOGkEtkx2LJ-RE%20Fp9MZqxC4SoURiED2ZCFZ1yyGEznZnPJ8LmSThCIW6DA-hwRvNJKIKAMBVO2RF9psAHoPcgAPIAaWQIgNmCNcO8lsCBmWSt5arIACIHfGBV7fX7Mtr1HCXbd3QgU97-aVg2ziXAAWXGi02hDOhGlkxQ8gjcgvdJ4sX1Jzq-NbPdHs8Zibwxh-B8JX84NCcD2kvbiIGgA)

[Solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzMg3gKGcuAcwgC5kQBXAWwCNoBuPZGqCCAEzIGcwpRDGAXxw4IlKsgDKAeyhgAIsFYIwwaSGxM4XBMgC8yAOTaEhgDRN2EHfqNWd5nMJyhIsRChlyAPABUAfJr4CNIANtQgAHJwVKTIANYQAJ7SMMi+lkoQKmogZF4KWTnqTiKu0PBIaHxuwHAAShAAjhTWCmDSfoG4+FyyYPn9XaU4YEkADp79AIqtUEldtgAKcHJ1od6NIVDs3okpab5mUv2Kyqrq-v4iMBQgxRo0FMCh7AWz0AsBABRMCDXQOpkVAAvgNZqtHjyDpdCwASkGcg+80WPWQwDS3wAhP9gLU4MgAD6E5A40F1AB0fTkcKC+GQrDAFCgGiwwnw7OQIRAPGwXLCEWisWO7CKFw0glsuPxVP6InwjOZrIA2iFwlQojEIABdMii865SXaE5IuZfa7Obm86lgZFJRG2s3edBgQIGNk4G12ilEFAGApnbLin02AD0oeQAHkANLIERWzA2h3OjBuulqwVasgAIl92eO4aj0cyBvUDsDDxDCALEZjpQTXPJcGBTcaLTa0M6LrTaKTyBtyHD0ni9fUvPb81sTxebxmTu732lgLgcJwE6SPuIOCAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here `return { [columnName]: direction }`.

This notation means `{[prop: string]: SortDirection}` when you expect `Record<keyof T, SortDirection>`

From my experience, TS does not play well with computed object properties. 99% it will be narrowed to indexed type `{[prop: string]: unknown}`.

To fix this problem, I made a `record` function which will return `Record<keyof T, unknown>`.

How I did it? I just added one overloading to the function.

Is this 100% percent good solution?
No, because it is a good practice to define more than one overloading.

I would say that overloading is a bit safer than type casting (`as` operator), but only a bit.

So I just defined the returned type of `record` function.

```js
function record<K extends Keys, V = unknown>(key: K, value: V): { [prop in K]: V }
function record<K extends Keys, V = unknown>(key: K, value: V) {
  return { [key]: value }
}
```

Because next notation does't work:

```js
function record<K extends Keys, V = unknown>(key: K, value: V): { [prop in K]: V } {
  return { [key]: value } // error
}
```

Here you have full example:

```js
interface Cat {
  age: number;
  breed: string;
}

enum SortDirection {
  asc = 'asc',
  desc = 'desc',
}

interface Sort<T> {
  columnName: keyof T
  direction: SortDirection
}

interface CriteriaRequestDto<T> {
  sort: Sort<T>
}

type Keys = string | number | symbol;

function record<K extends Keys, V = unknown>(key: K, value: V): { [prop in K]: V }
function record<K extends Keys, V = unknown>(key: K, value: V) {
  return { [key]: value }
}


type SortQuery<T> = Partial<Record<keyof T, SortDirection>>

function buildSortQuery<T>(
  criteria: CriteriaRequestDto<T>,
): SortQuery<T> {
  if (!criteria || !criteria.sort) {
    return {}
  }
  const { columnName, direction } = criteria.sort

  return record(columnName, direction)
}

const sortQuery: SortQuery<Cat> = {}
sortQuery.age = SortDirection.asc // OK 

const sort: Sort<Cat> = {
  columnName: "age", // OK
  direction: SortDirection.asc, // OK
}
const criteria: CriteriaRequestDto<Cat> = {
  sort: sort //ok
}
const query = buildSortQuery<Cat>(criteria)
query.age
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzMg3gKGcuAcwgC5kQBXAWwCNoBuPZGqCCAEzIGcwpRDGAXxw4IlKsgDKAeyhgAIsFYIwwaSGxM4XBMgC8yAOTaEhgDRN2EHfqNWd5nMJyhIsRChlyAPABUAfJr4CNIANtQgAHJwVKTIANYQAJ7SMMi%20lkoQKmogZF4KWTnqTiKu0PBIaHxuwHAAShAAjhTWCmDSfoG4%20FyyYPn9XaU4YEkADigA0slctjx8IITIAD7k1HRQq8hcSbRhjDgwFCDFGsqy7N5TyBAAHpAg7HMzSVxmyABqtifxINIAdxA-gAFIkkmQph8AG5wcJxT4ASjIWGQAG1xlBpONkKBkFMALpkb7CY6nVTqZAXKBXG73R7PfGzD7fAy-f5A0HgyEwuGtYmIoJUiBgChQDSotHgonIWHw5DCZyjCaefoARVaUCSXVsAAU4HI6qFvI0QjTvODUukPgVFMoKcD-CIyWdmBRgKF2AUNdBtQEQUwEDVoHUyKhg3wGs1Wjx5B0uhZkVJ1Zq-d0mMA0iCAIRB4C1OCrNa5iN1AB0fTkgp6%20GFovF2GE%20CbyBCIB42FbYQi0ViH3YRQdCtseYLFf6InwrHr52ylxBIXCVCiMQg-cHuURIzbHcrYB9WsGcgP2vQYECBiwwj3J7LRBQBltG-Ud5sAHo38gAPI3EQ7zB7keYDeGeF5CouParmQABE97QR8H7flMmT2rkQF2tkDqvggCGfj%20pT-q2pZwGGxGNC0bRxp0oG2DWgE7P0yAftI8QEeoHYUVqtg0O6nreqmIEYKCo4hnAW6cUkd7EDgQA)

**UPDATE**
Please take a look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oOAJwJYDsDmUAPlDgK4C2ARhBkWiFQPYA2A3AFDsBmpOAxsCyMcUDBD6MMAEwA8MKBAAewCDilI4iADRQAaiii8A1jkYB3HAD4AFEfgAuWDoBuAQ2akIj3QEpHAbygAbTAMRjAoXFgAXW8oAF9uXgEhETEJaTkFZVV1WHgEHX1UY1MLGzsQRxgXd09vHyh-dihRCGBSDBFAoMrYqDcPaETE9lwVDC5XPmgAYVdgJpaoVzwvEgpqDA5WyjEIKUd0bHwOUdUKKABlSWAAESx0wWEl1tcEPgMAcne%20L61llIIB9vkCPv92KNxjQpjNrrcZAAVSyvKASDzkHAAOVc5HWlUYXCgiMBj3EzxwjhuGHuZJSwkhnGhk2mc2wEywrgAShAAI6edB3YCMJEo5qtBC3KkI5GM9igSDwmkARU8GBAooMAAVXDTOcwZDyMrICUTETpqbSnqlLJZODx%20BSoJRSFhmFJLaqaBrkdZlnx2TROY5ZoHsNy%20QL7sLRQC-ErgF71ZrxZEidYAIQBrAc1xEYhZsOcgB0kppjVTrTEHS6TUSrXraOE6CaTYx2NxEB0UjpTviBmzudLt04VfanTS4kkUms6IoHbx3d7qR8cokOBbZcTaqqCaTGvmwBRqH8iS3%20%20Lq2gqEtD2twkvIIA9E%20oAB5eScdebqUJmSH49UTnTEcTxRwACIr3AnQX3fGBSXvSkEzvclUkfPgYNfD9GW-RZByDVwQyLCN%20WBaMRQAgxUy3I5bigF9GCMHDm0WUj1QMF03Q9W593-BYbHw8NVzYkBLzWdggA). You should not use `as` operator

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The `as Partial Record` will do the job

Comment: @Minaro Could you please share in TS playground your code? I tried to make my solution without `as` operator (type casting). I think it is possible to avoid it here

Comment: Sure, check the Solution or Playground links in my question

Comment: I made a small update. Try to avoid using `as`

Answer (score 2):

When you return `{ [columnName]: direction }` Typescript interprets the type as `{ [x: string]: SortDirection; }`.  This type has a `string` index signature and is therefore not assignable to `SortQuery<T>` which only allows keys of `T` as properties.  Typescript is basically making an assumption that if you create an object from a dynamic `string` key, then that object must allow *any* `string` key.  That assumption is false.

#### Spreading

On the other hand, if you add a dynamic property to an existing object by object spreading then Typescript keeps the type of the original object and basically ignores the extra property.

This is a bit of "hack" solution, but you won't have any errors if you add your sort to an empty object.

```
return {
  ...{},
  [columnName]: direction
}
```

Typescript interprets the returned object as type `{}` which is fine to assign to `SortQuery<T>` since all properties in `SortQuery<T>` are optional.

#### Intermediate Variable

We can create an empty object with the `SortQuery<T>` type, assign our sort to it, and then return it.

```
const query: SortQuery<T> = {};
query[columnName] = direction;
return query;
```

You could also spread a property onto it. This is basically the same as my "Spreading" solution but it feels like less of a hack since we know that the initial object is of the `SortQuery<T>` type instead of type `{}`.

```
const query: SortQuery<T> = {};
  
return {
  ...query,
  [columnName]: direction
}
```

#### Assertion

You can also just assert that the return type is correct using `as` because you know that it's right even if if Typescript doesn't.

```
return {
  [columnName]: direction
} as SortQuery<T>
```

Comment: Nice trick! I have never used spread syntax that way