# How to infer type of object with dynamic key in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

The code below gives me the following error when calling `useObject`:

> Argument of type `{ [x: string]: string; }` is not assignable to parameter of type `{ [K in keyof T]: string; }`. ts(2345)

```
class Magic<T> {
  useKey(key: keyof T): void {
    this.useObject({ [key]: 'Hello' });
  }

  private useObject(object: { [K in keyof T]: string }): void {
    // Please note that this is a simplified example. In my real scenario
    // this interface is provided by an external package so it cannot change.
    console.log(object);
  }
}
```

[Open in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyYHMCWwA8AVAfNA3gKGmgFcIBTAaVIE8AKAa2oC5oGqB7AM2nQEpmA3NkgAmuAoWgAXABZIIAOhKkA8gCMAVqWCSaOaAG1WAXWYByABKkQINqegBfHgG5x9vOIAOAJyT8wk0mIyNU1tGjYNLUlmPX1yaCQAOxZqTm4TaAhJH0SEBz5oQRExCWhgNkSINhBSeRsEcMjtZ1c8eyA)

I would expect value `{ [key]: 'Hello' }` to be inferred as type `{ [K in keyof T]: string }`, but instead it's inferred as `{ [K: string]: string }`.

I have tried adding `as const` to no avail. A manual cast to the expected type works, but requires me to define the (sometimes complex) type, which should be unnecessary because the types are available in the context.

What can I do to let TypeScript infer this type correctly?

Comment: I'd willing to bet that this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66615353/typescript-generic-to-transform-object-property-in-key-value-object/66615894#66615894